# Django Web Application Reverse for '/register' not found. '/register' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Django, and have one problem. I'm learning with a book "Django Web Application" that is quite old I think.

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"> </head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<span class="logo">Bookmarks</span> 
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<ul class="menu">
<li {% if section == "dashboard" %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
<a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Panel główny</a> </li>
<li {% if section == "images" %}class="selected"{% endif %}> <a href="#">Obrazy</a>
</li>
<li {% if section == "people" %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
<a href="#">Osoby</a> </li>
           </ul>
         {% endif %}
<span class="user">
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
Witaj, {{ request.user.first_name }}!
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Wyloguj</a> {% else %}
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Zaloguj</a> {% endif %}
</span>
</div>
<div id="content">
{% block content %} {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import include, url 
import account.views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls', namespace='app')),
    url(r'^account/', include('account.urls')),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**urls.py x2**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),

    url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login 
from .forms import LoginForm, UserRegistrationForm
# Create your views here.   
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(username=cd['username'], 
                                password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse("Login Succesfull")
                else:
                    return HttpResponse("Account is blocked")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Can't log in")
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            new_user.save()
            return render(request, 'account/register_done.html', {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

I still have error that say 'Reverse for '/register' not found. '/register' is not a valid view function or pattern name. In template /Users/danielczerepak/www/apka/shop-app/app_rama/templates/base.html, error at line 13
'

Comment: Your `base.html` likely contaisn a `{% url '/register' %}` whereas it should be `{% url 'register' %}`

Comment: Where can I find or check it?

Comment: Search for /register in your code base. One of them is being used as a string to `reverse` or `url`.

Comment: show me your base.html

Comment: I had a issue in a html file, I gave url  /account but should be url account